# Advice on leading sitting group

Tags: theravada, meditation-recommendation

I've been practicing for about a half dozen years now, have been fortunate to go on several retreats and have a consistent practice. Where I'm currently living I really don't have access to a sitting group I don't have any delusions about being a teacher but several people who know I sit have expressed  interest in learning.

I was considering doing simple guided sits. Are there any cautions? Should I probably not pursue this without training?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is good to start a sitting group. My suggestions are:

- Make the group as informal & self-reliant as possible. 'Self-reliant' means making it clear that meditation is an activity of self-practise & self-endeavour; that the group provides individual members the support & opportunity to develop their own practise.
- Make it clear/overt it is simply an informal sitting group rather than a    formal teaching facility.
- Provide guided meditation only to newcomers or when introducing a new
  practise.
- Keep guided meditation short (e.g. 10 - 15 minutes) & main meditation long
  (e.g. 30 minutes).
- If there is no guided meditation, do a text reading at the start, 
  contributed & read by yourself or by a member of the group.
- If possible, end with tea & formal group discussion on a topic,  chosen
  by yourself or by another member of the group.
- Be as 'democratic' as possible but without expanding into other
  spiritual traditions that may cause confusion.